# Run jboss 7.1 as service in domain mode in windows environment

Tags: jboss

I run the Jboss 7.1 as a service, but when I deploy the war through console it got deployed in data folder inside standalone folder.

[To run Jboss 7.1 as service I refered to this link](http://akhilesh-humbe.blogspot.in/2014/06/run-jboss-application-server-as-windows.html)

It seems that Jboss getting started in standalone mode when I run it as a service.

Comment: Please clearify your issue and the problem that you are facing

Comment: I runs Jboss 7.1 as service on windows but it gets started in standalone mode but I want to start Jboss in domain mode. I want to know is there any extra configuration requires to start Jboss as a service in domain mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an assumption, but have you tried replacing the run.bat properly with domain.bat rather than standalone.bat (the latter is shown in the post you followed)?

Comment: I will try it. Thanks for suggestion